# Best approach for keep UIView on across the app except few screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow

I knew this question might be reason for down vote but still I would really know the concept which I could use. I have a UIView, which I have added on the UIWindow. I need that view on almost few screen and not to others screen so which is the best way handle this case.

Thought about notification and delegate, Please, suggest.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  You added a UIView to a UIWindow - are you overlaying UIWindows? - unless you mean maybe you added a UIView to a UIViewController.  You also say "I need that view on almost few screen", so you mean you need it on a few screens but not the other?  Unless I misunderstand your question, you should just add it to each screen, correct?  Your last sentence confuses me also - "notification and delegates"?

Comment: I have added view to window, that view I want to show on few controller's view on other places I want to hide it. is this clear to you? last sentance is about to handle caese where can get to know where I should hide it or not. you got my point.

Comment: I have added UIview on window  in app delegate class and have global property to access it.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, there is a singleton object called the sharedApplication. You can use it to get your app delegate from anywhere in the code this way:

> MyAppDelegate* del = (MyAppDelegate*) [UIApplication
>   sharedApplication].delegate;

If you add a method to your app delegate, say "`showSharedView:(BOOL)b`", then all you have to do is call this from the viewWillLoad method of each of your controllers. (Assuming the view is an mar of the App delegate - which you say you have done).

For example:

> MyAppDelegate* del = (MyAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
>   [del showSharedView:NO];